# MySQL PHP - Inserting form data into tables. Unknown Error

Tags: php, mysql, database

So as the title stated, I'm trying to insert data into 2 tables if the form passes a few conditions (the user is logged in, the user hasn't voted on that product before, all of the fields have been filled in).

It was inserting the data into both tables perfectly when the condition was just:

```
$sql = "SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
```

But I realized that if the user had voted on any of the products, their username would appear in the table and they would fail the condition without having voted on the product. So I just added:

```
$sql = "SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='$username' AND productid='$id' LIMIT 1";
```

and now if I try to submit data to the database, it always returns the 'Error inserting into votes table' message but doesn't return the mysql_error() and obviously doesn't insert a new row into the votes table, but strangely it does update the products table.

I just can't figure out what's going on, so if anyone could help me diagnose the problem, I'd really appreciate it! Here's the code:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if($_POST['slider_surface'] !== "0" && $_POST['slider_edgewear'] !== "0" && $_POST['slider_centering'] !== "0" && $_POST['slider_corners'] !== "0"){
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'root';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            if(! $conn )
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

            $slider_surface = $_POST['slider_surface'];
            $slider_edgewear = $_POST['slider_edgewear'];
            $slider_centering = $_POST['slider_centering'];
            $slider_corners = $_POST['slider_corners'];
            $id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
            session_start();
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            //check if user has already voted
            mysql_select_db('products');
            $sql = "SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='$username' AND productid='$id' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            $uname_check = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if ($username){
                if ($uname_check < 1) {


                    $sql =  "INSERT INTO votes ".
                            "(username,productid,votesurface,voteedgewear,votecentering,votecorners,datetime) ".
                            "VALUES('$username','$id','$slider_surface','$slider_edgewear','$slider_centering','$slider_corners', now())";

                    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                    $id='';

                    // Make sure the _GET product ID is set, and sanitize it
                    $id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);

                    //Retrieves data from MySQL 
                    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                    $product = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

                    $newvotecount = $product['votecount'] + 1;
                    $newsum_surface = $product['sumsurface'] + $slider_surface;
                    $newsum_edgewear = $product['sumedgewear'] + $slider_edgewear;
                    $newsum_centering = $product['sumcentering'] + $slider_centering;
                    $newsum_corners = $product['sumcorners'] + $slider_corners;

                    $sql =  "UPDATE products SET votecount='{$newvotecount}', sumsurface='{$newsum_surface}', sumedgewear='{$newsum_edgewear}', sumcentering='{$newsum_centering}', sumcorners='{$newsum_corners}' WHERE id='$id'";

                    $retval2 = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );


                    if(! $retval){
                        die('Error inserting into votes table: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    else if(! $retval2){
                        die('Error inserting into products table: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    $grading_error = 'success';
                    mysql_close($conn);
                } else
                    $grading_error = 'duplicateuser';
        } else
            $grading_error = 'nouser';
        }
    else
        $grading_error = 'emptyfields';}
?>
```

Comment: Please, add `die($sql)` just before executing the `INSERT` and let us know what is the actual SQL like

Comment: may be quotes is the problem... try this `"INSERT INTO votes "."(username,productid,votesurface,voteedgewear,votecentering,votecorners,datetime) "."VALUES('".$username."','".$id."','".$slider_surface."','".$slider_edgewear."','".$slider_centering."','".$slider_corners."', now())";`

Comment: The logic seems a bit screwy. Is a `SELECT` even necessary? Also, now would be a really good time to learn about PDO and/or mysqli_

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this statement to do ? $sql = "SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='$username' AND productid='$id' LIMIT 1"; it returns the id u just passed if the username `$username` is present, and a null otherwise.

Comment: Seconding @OscarPérez, `die($sql)` one at a time before each sql and log it, or `echo $sql` after each $sql assignment

Comment: @OscarPérez Hi Oscar, I added `die($sql)` and it returns `SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='magmar' AND productid='52' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @AnudeepBulla I was trying to check whether the user has already voted on that product, so if it passes the ID, it means that the user has already voted and it should display the relevant error message. Is it wrong? Also, I did die($sql) and got `SELECT productid FROM votes WHERE username='magmar' AND productid='52' LIMIT 1` in return

Comment: @user2910809 I meant to put `die($sql);` before executing the sentence that is failing. I guess it should be one of the `INSERT` statements?

Comment: @OscarPérez if I put the `die($sql);` statement before `mysql_query( $sql, $conn );` of the INSERT that I am getting the error about I get `INSERT INTO votes (username,productid,votesurface,voteedgewear,votecentering,votecorners,datetime) VALUES('magmar','52','7','6','5','5', now())` Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, @user2910809 . It is exactly what I wanted to know. Now, if you execute this sentence directly from a MySQL client (i.e. PHPMyAdmin), does it produce any error?

Comment: @OscarPérez It gives me an error message of:  `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'magmar' for key 'username'` hmmmm... With that in mind I checked the table and see that username is set to 'unique'...

Comment: Ok @user2910809 , so, I'm going to write an answer. If it was your problem, please accept it.

Comment: @OscarPérez I used `ALTER TABLE votes DROP INDEX username` to set unique off and now it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem when inserting data to table, so there must be an error with the `INSERT` statement.
As @user2910809 says in previous comments, the `sql` evaluates as:

```
INSERT INTO votes (username,
                   productid,
                   votesurface,
                   voteedgewear,
                   votecentering,
                   votecorners,
                   datetime) 
           VALUES ('magmar',
                   '52',
                   '7',
                   '6',
                   '5',
                   '5',
                   now())
```

This sentence is syntactically correct. So, if there's an error, it must be with the inserted values.

As @user2910809 states on his comments, there's a `UNIQUE` key on `username` column, and it is what was throwing the error.

So the solution is to modify table's indexes to allow multiple rows with the same `username`.

**Edit**: as suggested in comments, the SQL to solve this problem was: `ALTER TABLE votes DROP INDEX username;`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I did and it worked. For anyone that ends up in the same situation, you can get rid of the unique attribute with `ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX constraint_name` thanks again @OscarPérez

Comment: @Oscar Wouldn't it be better to include the SQL in the answer to better help future stumblers ?